# CodeIgniter Performance load view multiple times vs loop in view

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

I'm trying to solve possible scaling performance issue. Is there a more clear performance benefit to these two scenarios:

### Scenario 1:

Make several calls to load a view and pass a small amount of data each time

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('table_head');
    $results = $this->db->select('*')->from('table')->get()->result_array();
    foreach ($results as $key)
    {
        $this->load->view('table_row', $key);
    }
    $this->load->view('table_foot');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

View table_head

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

View table_row

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $var_a; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $var_b; ?></td>
            ...
        </tr>
```

View Table_foot

```
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

### Scenario 2:

Make 1 call to load a view and pass a large amount of data

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->data['results'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('table')->get()->result_array();
    $this->load->view('table', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

View table

```
...
<table>
    <thead>Header Info...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($results as $key): ?>
            <tr>echo row information as needed</tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
<table>
...
```

I've been using scenario 1 because it is helping to keep my application modular and keep the MVC format by keeping logic loops in the controller. But say the result from the SQL call is 1000 entries, or even more, is there a clear performance difference between the two scenarios? Am I attempting to make my application too modular? I do try to recycle as much of my code as I can, and as a result more of my methods will load at minimum 8 views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I broke down and wrote a small script to inflate my table for these testing purposes. Here are the results of my small test. To keep the tests equivalent, I only change which view I am displaying.

### Scenario 1

Controller:

```
public function results()
{
    $this->load->view('headers/header', $this->default_lib->viewdata());
    $this->load->view('body_bits/bodyopen');
    $this->title['title'] = 'Testing Tesults';
    $this->title['link'] = 'tests';
    $this->title['link_text'] = 'Back to Tests';
    $this->load->view('body_bits/page_title', $this->title);
    $this->load->view('tests/results_open');

    $results = $this->db->select('*')->
        from('test_results')->
        where('software', 'nwralpha')->
        order_by('time', 'ASC')->
        //limit('10')->
        get()->result_array();
    foreach ($results as $key)
    {
        $this->data['name'] = ucwords($this->ion_auth->user($key['user_id'])->row()->username);
        $this->data['time_taken'] = $key['time'];
        $this->data['test_taken'] = $key['test_type'];
        $this->data['common'] = ($key['common_codes'] == 1) ? 'Common Code List' : 'Full Code List';
        $this->data['date'] = $key['date'];

        $this->load->view('tests/results', $this->data);
    }

    $this->load->view('tests/results_close');
    $this->load->view('body_bits/bodyclose');
    $this->load->view('footers/footer');
}
```

View

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $time_taken; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $test_taken; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $common; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
</tr>
```

### Scenario 2

Controller:

```
public function results()
{
    $this->load->view('headers/header', $this->default_lib->viewdata());
    $this->load->view('body_bits/bodyopen');
    $this->title['title'] = 'Testing Tesults';
    $this->title['link'] = 'tests';
    $this->title['link_text'] = 'Back to Tests';
    $this->load->view('body_bits/page_title', $this->title);
    $this->load->view('tests/results_open');

    $results = $this->db->select('*')->
        from('test_results')->
        where('software', 'nwralpha')->
        order_by('time', 'ASC')->
        //limit('10')->
        get()->result_array();

    $this->data['results'] = $results;
    $this->load->view('tests/resultsloop', $this->data);

    $this->load->view('tests/results_close');
    $this->load->view('body_bits/bodyclose');
    $this->load->view('footers/footer');
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($results as $key): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo ucwords($this->ion_auth->user($key['user_id'])->row()->username); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['time']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['test_type']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['common_codes']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['date']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

#### Results

I tested both examples with 1004 results and with 11004 results and here is what I found using CodeIgniter's built in Profiler

**1004 Results**

Scenario 1 Average Load Time: 1.94462    Seconds
Scenario 2 Average Load Time: 1.1723    Seconds

**11004 Results**

Scenario 1 Average Load Time: 19.78867 Seconds
Scenario 2 Average Load Time: 11.81502 Seconds

### What This Means

For anyone else who just wants to know the answer and not read this whole post:
While Separation of logic and HTML is the point of MVC frameworks, There are acceptable cases where you can use logic to determine how to display information. In this case, I only used a loop to keep spitting out uniform information as needed. This test shows that it is more efficient to make the least amount of view calls.

Comment: Nice! I never thought of applying scenario 1 and never will after this post.

Answer (score 0):

imho the controller hands off the relevant assets -- to the correct view. 
for example if you did not get any results back -- the course of action for a "no results" condition - should happen in the controller. (versus checking to see if $results exists in your view)

The logic for -- How do we Display the Results? -- happens in the View. The controller passes $results, the View then is responsible for how those results are displayed. With scenario #1, you have to go into your controller, to make changes to the page design.

And when $results are too large.... then use pagination.

Comment: Just a couple of notes for this, if `$results` is returned empty, it will never enter the `foreach` loop, and therefore the controller is already performing the logic for all result options. I know I have the option (almost a requirement) for pagination, but considering if a user wishes to view a large set of data at one time, which scenario works better.